# Format phone number using Eval

Tags: asp.net, formatting, label, eval

I am trying to format a phone number (stored as string) in a label on an .aspx page using Eval but am having trouble getting it to work.  I have tried doing this in the following ways:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhoneNumber", "{0:(###) ###-####}")%>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Eval("PhoneNumber")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

I know I can create a method to format the string, but I am only displaying the phone number once in this app and am not concerned with reusability - plus I'm curious to know if it can be done using Eval.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can not put your code in the Text attribute of the Label tag. This will cause an error "The server tag is not well formed".

You should put your code inside the tags

Below is an example:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"><%# !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Eval("PhoneNumber"))) ? String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToInt64(Eval("PhoneNumber").ToString())) : String.Empty%></asp:Label>
```

Comment: So your addition was the `ToString` method?

Comment: Yes sir. I made a mistake?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it did not work.  Format remained the same.  Also, it throws NullReferenceException if a record does not have a phone number.

Comment: It is always best to describe your answers a bit.  If you, don't the answer can be deletes for being low quality.  check the FAQ if any of this sounds unfamiliar

Comment: @AndrewPaes that would work as long as PhoneNumber is guaranteed to be a number... and as long as you don't have an area code over 213. The max value of `Int32` is `2,147,483,647` or as a phone number, `(214) 748-3647`.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I changed to Int64 but, and if don't have an area code the code need one more validation. Thanks for considerations.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to centralize a function for formatting phone numbers as you will probably do this in more than one place. You could do something like:

```
public static class Toolkit
{
    public static string FormatPhone(string n)
    {
        string returnNumber = n;
        //Handle US Phones (10 digits) or else don't format
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(n) && n.Length == 10)
        {
            string areaCode = n.Substring(0, 3);
            string usPrefix = n.Substring(3, 3);
            string usNum = n.Substring(6, 4);
            returnNumber = String.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", areaCode, usPrefix, usNum);
        }
        return returnNumber;
    }
}
```

And then call it in your repeater:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# YOURNAMESPACE.Toolkit.FormatPhone(Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PhoneNumber")))%>'></asp:Label>
```

Of course, it might be cleaner to just format the phone number before it is passed as the datasource... or you could do it on the DataBound event if you are doing more formatting. Also, I think your formatting would work against a number but not a string.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old, but a simpler way would be to utilize the built-in RegEx.Replace:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Regex.Replace(Eval("PhoneNumber"), "(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)", "($1)$2-$3")%>' />
```